# Sending mails using java Mail from emails under any domain

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am using the Java Mail Api to send emails from my application using the following code:

```
private void sendMail()
{
    final String username = "uname@mydomain.com";
    final String pasword = "password";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "email.secureserver.net");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", 465);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", 465);
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() 
    {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username,pasword);
        }
    });
    try 
    {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(senderEmail));
        message.setSubject(messageSubject);
        message.setText(messageBody);
        Transport.send(message);
    } 
    catch (MessagingException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This code works fine if I use emails under `gmail` if the `mail.smtp.host` value is `smtp.gmail.com`. But currently I am using an email created using `godaddy.com`.

The error I get is:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: email.secureserver.net, port: 465;
 nested exception is:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect.
```

I also tried the following code:
http://www.javaquery.com/2011/09/how-to-send-mail-from-godaddy-java-mail.html

but still I am unable to send emails. Is there any solution for this

Comment: Including the error message in your question is always a good idea. Seeing as you're using Gmail's SMTP server does it surprise you that you can't specify an arbitrary domain?

Comment: it seems your smtp parameters are still set to google. try changing it to the domain/host/port of your new email addr

Comment: @mattymanme, is there any way to find all the required property values for any given email address

Comment: No, there is not.  If you have an email account at godaddy.com you should've been given the information necessary to connect to their mail server.

Comment: BTW, you might want to fix these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).